# Reading excel with the driver xlsx vb6

Tags: excel, vb6, xlsx, vba

I'm having a problem during one week, and I couldn't find the solution. I'm trying to read a file in xlsx on vb6 as a component of the asp classic.

First issue that I couldn't be able to solve was this

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim provider As String
provider = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xlsx)};DBQ=" & nomArq & ";"
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open provider
```

The error that I got in this connection was

> "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

The second try was in this way

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
'Dim provider As String
With cn
    .provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & nomArq & ";" & ";Extended Properties=\""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes\;"""
    .Open
End With
```

And the erros was

> "Format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification."

I also tried in another way and I got the error:

> "could not find installable isam"

but I don't have the code hear anymore.

someone could help me, I looked in all most everything on google

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you are trying to do but it seems like you are trying to establish a connection (looking at your code).....try something like this with what you are doing....

```
Dim g_cnDB as ADODB.Connection
Set g_cnDB as ADODB.Connection
g_cnDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=TEXT;User ID=TEXT; Pwd=TEXT; Initial Catalog=TEXT; Data Source=TEXT"
'Then set it's timeout to be unlimited, so your connection remains open until you close it
g_cnDB.CommandTimeout = 0
'Establishing the connection
g_cnDB.Open
```

Comment: yeah, I asked for help, for a friend mine, and I did almost the same thing, so thank you so much